# построение unity проекта под платформу android

Tags: android, unity3d

Как сделать что бы после сборки проекта в unity под android формировался не apk файл а sln решение для Visual Studio в котором уже можно вносит с помощью Xamarin правки в изначальный скрипт написанный в unity  и работать с стемами android - такими как гироскоп и акселерометр? 
Спрашиваю т.к на Windows Phone делается именно так - смотрел туториал  - но на android так не выходит.

Comment: Wtf? причем тут apk и sln, почему в sln нужно вносить правки через Xamarin в какой-то скрипт? Windows phone это чье детище? а Visual Studio? Microsoft же. У ios - xcode =apple. У каждой платформы свои способы билда. У android еще android studio есть, либо просто через android SDK. Написал бы что тебе надо от акселерометра и гироскопа( input.gyro, Input.acceleration)

Answer (score 1):

Зачем делать такие костыли?
Unity3d предоставляет API для работы с гироскопом. Вот, [пример в официальной доке](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope.html)

---

Вот еще есть [туториал](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/accelerometer-input), тоже, кстати, от Unity.

И там же небольшой пример кода.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AccelerometerInput : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update () 
    {
        transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x, 0, -Input.acceleration.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Опишите пример из оф.доку, добавие пример кода.